ROS2 Jazzy failing launch file on RPi5 only
I am having trouble getting my simple launch file to run on a raspberry pi 5, even though the same code runs fine on my more powerful PC. I am using ros jazzy.
Raspberry Pi 5

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Memory: 7.7 GiB memory
OS-Type: 64-bit
Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-1015-raspi

Simple launch files that just run robot_state_publisher, rviz, and joint_state_publisher usually run fine. But when I add in a control_manager, and controllers like the forward_command_controller and the joint_state_broadcaster, the launch file almost always fails, sometimes with different errors each time (even if no changes made to code). They all seem like errors to do with memory management.
Below are three examples of errors I've seen...
EXAMPLE 1

[ros2_control_node-3] [ERROR] [1733106993.988017872]
[controller_manager]: Caught exception of type :
N6rclcpp10exceptions8RCLErrorE while initializing controller
'my_forward_position_controller': could not create service: Failed to
register type for service, at ./src/rcl/service.c:198

EXAMPLE 2

[ros2_control_node-3] Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread
9739: [ros2_control_node-3] #3    Object "", at 0, in
[ros2_control_node-3] #2    Object "[vdso: 9682]", at 0xffff9a9eb7df,
in  [ros2_control_node-3] #1    Object
"/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libbackward.so", at 0xffff9a9891d3, in
backward::SignalHandling::sig_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
[ros2_control_node-3] #0    Object
"/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libbackward.so", at 0xffff9a988f97, in
[ros2_control_node-3] Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object
[(nil)])

EXAMPLE 3

[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1733107828.363338767]
[spawner_my_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed to configure controller
[ros2_control_node-3] [INFO] [1733107828.365289951]
[controller_manager]: Configuring controller:
'my_forward_position_controller' [ros2_control_node-3] terminate
called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc'
[ros2_control_node-3]   what():  std::bad_alloc [ros2_control_node-3]
terminate called recursively

Any insight into what might be causing this? I've seen two suggestions about messing with a swap file, but was thinking this wouldn't be necessary since 8GB ram seems decent. I see this when running "free"

total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8124112     3275424     2718600      648212     2974500     4848688
Swap:        1048572           0     1048572


Another note... if I run "free" while the launch file is running (with rviz and rsp working and controllers unconfigured, aka it half-fails), I still see between 4-5 GB free.

After uninstalling ros-desktop and installing ros-base, I'm also getting the error "Resource temproarily unavailable" for the joint state broadcaster.

Fixed it (with the help of support on the ros2_control github).
Once lock_memory: false is set in the controller_manager config YAML file it works.

please mark this question as resolved!

will do! just need to wait 1 day before accepting my own answer.

Just for context for other people who have this issue, the ros2_control GitHub issue is https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/1905. I also started having this issue yesterday across three different machines.

@danzimmerman, thank you! Sounds like they are planning on releasing a patch to make lock_memory: false the default
